# Find several shortest paths with A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, routes, shortest-path

I am making a routing application that uses A* algorithm for finding route. 
I want to offer not just one route, but also a few alternative routes. For example routes that are just a little bit longer than the optimal one.

Since A* (and many others) find only one route, how can I search for these alternative ones? Should I use some other algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into research on the [K shortest paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing) problem, which is the problem of finding the k shortest paths between two nodes. The algorithm described on the Wikipedia page is a generalisation of [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

> To find the shortest path one can use shortest path algorithms such
>   as Dijkstra’s algorithm or Bellman Ford algorithm and extend them to
>   find more than one path. The K Shortest path routing algorithm is a
>   generalization of the shortest path problem. The algorithm not only
>   finds the shortest path, but also K other paths in order of increasing
>   cost. K is the number of shortest paths to find. The problem can be
>   restricted to have the K shortest path without loops (loopless K
>   shortest path) or with loop.

Some key papers and concepts:

- [Finding the k shortest paths](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-SJC-98.pdf), David Eppstein, 1997
- A [description of the problem](http://www.mat.uc.pt/~eqvm/OPP/KSPP/KSPP.html)
- [Yen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen's_algorithm): "The algorithm assumes that the Dijkstra algorithm is used to find the shortest path between two nodes, but any shortest path algorithm can be used in its place." Presumably A* can be used. A Google code page of various implementations can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/k-shortest-paths/).
- A detailed [Bibtex bibliography](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/bibs/kpath.bib) on the topic, compiled by Eppstein.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to run [A*-epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Bounded_relaxation) with increasing value of epsilon.

With each iteration, as epsilon grows, the path found is expected to be longer - and the time for finding it to be shorter.